# Сместить текст в блоке на 50%

Tags: html, css

У меня есть текст в блоке `х`. Высота блока `200px` я пытаюсь сделать `padding` сверху. Логика мне говорит, что если высота блока `200px` то `padding-top:50%` опустит текст на 100px но вместо этого текст уходит намнооого ниже. Почему это не работает и как в таком случае правильно разместить текст посередине `x` блока?

```css
.x {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  /*width: 100%;*/
}

.x p {
  padding-top: 50%;
}

.container {
  min-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="x">
      <p>2019</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Увы, "центром" элемента считается не центр, как иногда хотелось бы, а левая-верхняя точка этого элемента.

[image: ...]
[image: ...]

Для того, чтобы отцентрировать элемент по центру родителя, есть множество вариантов:

**margin: auto;**

Для этого способа, у дочернего элемента должна быть фиксированный размер.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
</div>
```

**position и transform**

Этот вариант будет проще всех, наверное, к тому же ему всё всё равно какой размер будет у родителя или дочернего элемента.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
</div>
```

**position и calc()**

Как вариант, но тут есть жёсткие условия использования.
Размеры родителя должны быть фиксированные, центрирование должно быть тоже фиксированным.

```css
.parent {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: relative;
}

.children {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(50% - 100px / 2);
  /* 100px / 2 - половина высоты этого элемента */
  top: calc(50% - 30px / 2);
  /* 30px / 2 - половина высоты этого элемента */
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
</div>
```

**flex'овский способ**

Здесь центрирование идёт не от дочерних элементов, как в предыдущих вариантах, а от родителя.
Из всех вариантов это более гибкий, подробнее о **flex** можно загуглить, материала вагон.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.children {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
</div>
```

**flex и margin: auto** (Спасибо [@Vearo](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015285/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-50/1015325?noredirect=1#comment1724582_1015325) за подсказку)

В отличие от варианта с `margin: auto` этот не требует "жёсткой фиксации" через `position: absolute;`.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  display: flex;
}

.children {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children">
</div>
```

**grid'овский способ**

Аналогично примеру с **flex**.
По поводу **grid**, так же можете загуглить.

```css
.parent {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: #c6eef3;
  border: 1px solid #aaddf0;
  border-radius: 20px;
  
  /* Относится к центрированию */
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.children {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  background: #f57988;
  border: 1px solid #e44b61;
  border-radius: 10px;  
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Еще как вариант, контейнеру: display: flex; блоку: margin: auto; встанет ровно в центр, без жестких размеров

Comment: @Vearo, спасибо за комментарий, добавил в ответ)

Answer (score 0):

Предлогаю использовать flex

```css
.x {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="x">
      <p>2019</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```