# Как сделать отображение модального окна посередине видимой области экрана?

Tags: css, jquery

Как сделать, чтобы вызванное модальное окно появлялось всегда в центре зоне видимости окна? С возможностью скролла этого окна.

Comment: про скролл не понял

Answer (score 3):

Обернуть это модальное окно в `div` и использовать флекс.

```css
.wrap {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="modal">Modal</div>
</div>
```

---

**UPD**

Вот ответ, где я собирал все известные мне способы, при помощи которых можно отцентрировать элемент по центру - [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015285/%D0%A1%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82-%D0%B2-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0-50/1015325#1015325)

Answer (score 3):

А вот по олдскульному ) Если нужен не flex ;)

```css
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0; top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

.modal {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 150px;
  background: #ddd;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="modal">Modal</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем "олдскульно" из-за `transform`. Но как вариант.