# Как выставить блок по центру экрана?

Tags: css, html5

У меня примерно вот такой случай, но не могу понять, как выставить `text` по центру экрана

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
.container .block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
 
 .container .block span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block'>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: А вы пробовали text-align: center?

Comment: @GGO так мне нужно именно по центру самого экрана)

Comment: нужно задать высоту родителю и flex'ом по центру сделать)

Comment: [Как выровнять содержимое по центру](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1015325/221218)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
 }
 
 .container .block span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block'>
    <span>TEXT</span>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

У вас проблемы с самым контейнером `container`. Если хотите чтоб он был равен высоте экрана, задайте ему `height: 100vh` вместо `height: 100%`

Comment: В моем случае, это действует как margin-top и блок уходит в самый низ) Поэтому нужно было использовать просто display: flex

Answer (score 1):

Еще как вариант, добавить

```
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

```css
html,
body{
  height: 100%;
}

body{
  margin: 0;
}

.container{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
 }
 
.container .block {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
 }
 
 .container .block span {
  color: #000;
  font-size: 35px;
 }
```

```html
<div class='container'>
  <div class='block'>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Точно, вот что я забыл!!! Помню же что когда-то так делал, спасибо за ответ и время!)